# Replace a string by another in cognos using oracle database

Tags: oracle, cognos

i have a string "/folder[@name='Location/louvre']/directory[@name='Documents']" and i want to replace /folder[@name= by "loc>pl", i'm using the replace function but it doesn't work so.

Comment: could show us how looks your sql?

Comment: Are you asking about a function in Cognos, or Oracle? It isn't clear in your question. Can you provide your existing function that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

works for me, 
remember about double quotes:

```
select 
 replace('/folder[@name=''Location/louvre'']/directory[@name=''Documents'']',
 '/folder[@name=',
 'loc>pl') 
from dual;
```